# Locust: How to assign a specific task in a taskset to a specific virtual user

Tags: task, assign, locust

So I have one user class, class User(HttpUser), and a taskset with 5 different tasks.  Now I spawn 5 virtual users. How can I restrict each user to a specific task in a taskset?

I have read the documentation but I don't see such topic.

Answer (score 0):

I don't think you can. You will need to isolate the taskset into different user classes in order to be able to better control everything